# Forms control that allows zoom, pan AND POI

Tags: c#, winforms, zooming, pan, point-of-interest

For my phD project I need to do microscopy imaging. I cooked up an application using C#/winforms/GDI that allows me to display my images, zoom/pan them and display a ruler.

However, the thing is quite buggy, although usable...

What I need now is some kind of system to store a list of POIs (points of interest) based on user interaction.

These points can be used to center the image on them/direct the imaging hardware to them etc...

I have no clue how to go about this in the most efficient way. There is at least one commercial control that pretty much does what I want but it is very expensive, not open source and intended for use on web forms.:

[Example Zoomcontrol](http://samples.dart.com/PowerWEB_Zoom_POI_CSharp/Webform1.aspx)

Who can help... deadlines are looming... :s

Comment: It's not really an answer (hence in a comment) but have you tried using WPF under .NET 3.5?  I thought that supported zoom and some other effects by default?  I haven't really used it though, so if this is false, then please ignore it.

Comment: If deadlines are looming, this wouldn't be the time to jump into WPF. I already attempted that. :)

Comment: Well the thing is... I have some experience with WPF because I need to align some "friggin' lasers" in my setup and for that I use a CCD camera (a webcam actually) and I needed to overlay some crosshairs on the video stream..

So I know WPF would be able to do all this but like some of you said... it might take time, more than I currently have, and the POI feature is still something that I would have to implement separately and it is the thing that gives me the most trouble...

Comment: Point of interests are gathered automatically or a user defines a region as  POI?

Comment: Kris, have you tried e-mailing the company and asking if you can have it as a student? (A lot of places have academic discounts, and if they don't you might be able to convince them to give the control free in exchange for recognition).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web browser inside your winform and try using jquery for zooming in. Refer the site http://plugins.jquery.com/project/imageZoom

Comment: Seriously dude, as if I am going to load a full web browser component to view an image in a native application. Not to mention that I then would have to first convert my data to some form of web content... and on top of that muck about with JQuery???? You must be delirious... The question was on Winforms and GDI.

Comment: @ Streppel... the above does NOT answer the question at all, link or not. I was asking about a Winforms issue and the answerer comues up with javaxcript/web technologies that are 100% beside the issue.